# How do I forward an action message to the next responder?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiresponder

if I have something like:

```
void maybeHandleMessage: sender: AnyObject {
    if isHandling() {
        handle()
    } else {
        // forward action message to next responder in the responder chain
    }
}
```

What code do I need in the else clause to forward the maybeHandleMessage?

Comment: [self.nextResponder doSomething:param];

Answer (score 0):

If your object is a kind of subclass of `UIResponder` there is a method

```
func nextResponder() -> UIResponder?
```

you can try

Comment: This is found in the cocoa event handling guide: "Warning: Although NSResponder declares a number of action messages, it doesn’t actually implement them. You should never send an action message directly to a responder object of an unknown class. Always use the NSApplication method sendAction:to:from:, the NSResponder methods tryToPerform:with: or doCommandBySelector:, or check that the target responds using the NSObject method respondsToSelector:."  So, is the only way to use the sendAction again?